# Creating new project in Eclipse from Github parent/child pom?

Tags: eclipse, maven, github

What's the correct way to create a project in Eclipse from a github project which uses the parent/child pom construct, for example https://github.com/vladmihalcea/vladmihalcea.wordpress.com ?

I can clone/download it ok, but then do I need to manually create an eclipse project for each sub-project within or is there a better way?

(Googled the hell of out this question without finding an answer, but please feel free to post a link if you know of such.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Import feature of Eclipse.

1. Select File / Import ... from the Eclipse menu.
2. From the Import dialog window, Select the Maven / Existing Maven Projects wizard option.
3. Click Next.
4. From the Import Maven Projects dialog, choose the root directory using the Browse directory chooser.
5. With the directory choosen, the dialog will be populated with all available Maven projects.  Check all the projects to be imported.
6. Click Finish.

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks Brent.